# IP пользователя и выбор

Tags: php

Как сделать сохранение IP пользователя во время авторизации?
Делаю по этому примеру: [ссылка](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=347&ru37)

И ещё. 
К примеру поле с выбором:  Москва, Воронеж, Берлин. При выборе города Москва, в БД должно сохраняться город Москва и страна Россия. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста выложите код, который у вас не получается реализовать.

Comment: В БД не надо сохранять "Россия" при каждом обращении. Вам надо завести таблицу со справочником городов, в которой будет указано, что Москва находится в России, тогда вы всегда сможете получить эти данные зная город

Comment: мне надо, чтобы сохранялось